# LDAP Exception Object Class Violation : Add new User

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ldap

I am trying to create a user in an LDAP directory, but I get the following error: "Object Class Violation". Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
try             
{
    DirectoryEntry ouEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://localhost:389/ou=people,dc=wso2,dc=com","cn=admin,dc=wso2,dc=com", "toto", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

    DirectoryEntry childEntry = ouEntry.Children.Add("CN=tati toto", "inetOrgPerson");
    childEntry.Properties["sn"].Add("toto");
    childEntry.CommitChanges();
}
catch(Exception Ex)             
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception : "+ Ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Anglais, s'il vous plait..

Comment: Are you sure the administrative account you're using has the proper permissions to create the user?

Comment: I believe you also need to set at least the `samAccountName` for new users and groups, and it has to be a unique value (unique within your domain container)

Comment: I use the administrative account. I also tried to set samAccountName but i get the following error : "attribute type undefined" and i always have this error : "LdapException: Matched DN: "

Answer (score 0):

i resolve it,

```
 try             
 {
DirectoryEntry ouEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://localhost:389/ou=people,dc=wso2,dc=com","cn=admin,dc=wso2,dc=com", "toto", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

DirectoryEntry childEntry = ouEntry.Children.Add("CN=tati toto", "top");
childEntry.Properties["objectclass"].Add("person");
childEntry.Properties["sn"].Add("toto");
childEntry.CommitChanges();
 }
 catch(Exception Ex)             
{
Console.WriteLine("Exception : "+ Ex.Message);
}
```